How do enemies detect me?
I have recently started playing the firearms-based roguelike, Jupiter Hell. However, I am curious about the awareness of the enemies. Do enemies always detect you right away, as soon as you can see them? Also, I have the impression that enemies can hear gunshots and will head that way to investigate. It seems that often, once you enter a new level and start shooting things, more enemies often seem to move towards your position. Is that correct?
It seems they can hear and respond to gunshots, but can they hear anything else? (e.g. doors opening, the player moving around, reloading)
I understand there are some stealth options with the Scout class (I haven't tried it yet), but I am talking about just general play (i.e. with the Marine).

It seems like you've already answered one of your questions. You appear to have already determined that enemies move towards you when you start shooting.

@Daemons it's a fair point. Although, if so it prompts some further questions: what can they hear and how far? Can they hear you moving around, doors opening?

Woah, this is a complex topic.
Enemies in Jupiter Hell have 3 different senses - sight, hearing and smell. All three of these vary between enemies - robots and humanoids don't actually have smell and have good sight and average hearing. Demons (especially fiends, reavers and cerberi) have a good smell, various hearing (some are deaf).
Vision works with a 1 turn mercy timer - so if an enemy sees you, they'll act against you next turn.
Hearing depends both on how well an enemy hears, as well as how loud something is. Most actions that you'd expect to emit sound do affect the hearing. Both the act of shooting and hitting something with a shot emits sound (shooting is usually louder, but not always, this depends on the weapon).
Smell is hardest to explain plainly - for simplicity reasons only the player emits smell (you stinker), and that smell creates a olfactory flow map of the level, thanks to which the fiends and reavers can track you down and often attack from the back.
Worth noting is that invisibility blocks only vision - you still emit sound, and more importantly it doesn't block smell!
If you have any further questions, you can try asking in a comment, or join the Jupiter Hell discord where many people have already a working knowledge of the internals :).

Thanks for the detailed answer - a lot of very helpful info here. Very cool to hear that the game has such a detailed awareness system. I had no idea the demons can smell you, ha ha! I wonder if there are some items you can find that can mask your scent? I will check out the Discord if I have any other questions about this, thanks again.

@KornelKisielewicz Great answer, really interesting info. Just wondering, where’d you get the answer info from?

@Daemons assuming it's not someone using his name, he is the creator of the game.

@user19513069 ohhh… question retracted.

Lol I love when devs answer questions about their own games

Um yeah, I'm the dev :). I somehow thought most of this was already wikified, modders do have access to the Lua side of the code so most of such mechanics are now able to be digged out.

@KornelKisielewicz Yeah no, I wasn’t able to find any of what you said on the Fandom (I wasn’t able to find a wiki.gg).

It's intuitive what better or worse hearing does (can perceive fainter sounds from further away) but do the other two senses have degrees, or is it a binary can see/can't see, can smell/can't smell? And if they have degrees, how do they work?

They have degrees. The player leaves a decaying scent (say 100 units) that decays each second (1 unmodified turn). A beings scent value is how faint of a scent it can pick up (say scent 20, means he can pick up 20 units and follow it). Sight has range in squares - some entities don't see as far as the player, but can smell him, which can lead to interesting emergent behaviour... Well, it would lead if the being wasn't shot on turn 1 of being visible :P

The noise page of the Fandom says most weapons cause some kind of noise when used:

Most weapons cause some kind of noise in game, which alerts enemies to the position of the source of the noise - usually you.

And... that's all it says. Nothing about any other noises, or what the noise range is (if there even is one).
However, there is some more info on the subpages of the interactives page. The main page lists multiple different  interactive objects that you can interact with. Almost all the interactives (excluding doors and crates) are hyperlinks to subpages.
For example, the vending machine subpage says,

When hit by the player [...]

Given that you have to hit it for it do anything, the sound of you using your weapon (as long as it's one of the ones with sfx) will attract nearby enemies. Same thing for the barrel subpage:

When they are destroyed [...]

You have to hit it for it do anything, which will cause a noise... etc.
These are the only interactives I could find on the interactive objects page that require using a weapon to interact with.

Thanks for your answer, this is helpful information. Although, it would still be good to find some specific info about what other actions generate noise and whether enemies spot the player immediately on a visual. I might be able to get a better handle on some of these things as I play through the game more.

@Time4Tea Yeah, I thought the answer was a bit lacklustre, just because of the sparse info in the Fandom. Feel free to post your own answer (or edit mine, I suppose, but your answer would probably be better).
